Cannot understand how to install drivers in Ubuntu
I just installed Ubuntu and my Bluetooth doesnt seem to work. after searching for a while i found out that https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:13d3-3563 it is supported but i have to download the drivers or something like that. How can i do that?

The driver should be included in the kernel. Does sudo systemctl enable bluetooth help?

Also, go to the additional drivers tab in software & sources. Does it help?

i did the sudo command but it didnt work

should i restart once? the additional drivers page shows "No additional drivers available"

The page you linked says device is supported by kernel versions 5.15 and newer. What kernel version do you have? Check with the command uname -a.

i am currently on my windows OS, will check when i open linux, i downloaded the latest Ubuntu if it helps.
